# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'sam-G5-5587' (111)

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I am new to *SQL*, I was trying to setup *SQL* and *SQL Workbench*, but when I tried to create a connection, I got this error:

[image: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)]

I tried a solution from the internet, to comment bind address in `mysqld.cnf` file, I did and restarted *SQL service*, but nothing changed. Furthermore, when I tried to write that command `mysql -u root -p` I got another error: 
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Comment: Is `mysqld` running? Assuming you have a systemd based system, `service mysql status` should tell you.  If it is running, you then need to figure out where it is listening - an IP (and which one) or a socket or both...

Comment: Please answer the questions of the comment above and additionally add the output of `ss -l -4` (Lists all open ports) to your question.

Comment: 1- Is mysqld running?
I typed "service mysql status" and I see in the Active: active(running)
O/P:
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: active (running) since So 2019-09-15 02:25:39 CEST; 26s ago
  Process: 18236 ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post (code=e
  Process: 18228 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exi
 Main PID: 18235 (mysqld)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─18235 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Comment: Dear Dirdi, 

can you write me the command to list all open ports?

Comment: Dear Ivan,

How to figure out where it is listening - an IP (and which one) or a socket or both?

Comment: I wrote "sudo netstat -tulpn", and here is the output:
 
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30647/cupsd     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6942          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31842/java      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:63342         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31842/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42255           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31842/java      
....

Comment: tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2182/dnsmasq    
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      30647/cupsd     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           6931/chrome

Comment: @SamehAbdelbadie: Please edit and extend your question instead of adding comments. It is hard for others to read output of commands without any formatting.